# linux sbc recommendations

Tags: linux, sbc

I realize this is nearly a dupe of [SBC Recommendations](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/sbc-recommendations) , but I have slightly different specs in mind.

Does anyone know of a single-quantity SBC with the following features?

- 32 bit CPU, something common e.g., x86, ppc, arm, atom
- capable of running some fairly modern variant of Linux
- built-in 100Mbit/s ethernet interface (preferably with RJ-45 jack)
- built-in RS-232 or RS-232C serial port (DB-9 connector desirable but not critical)
- capable of booting an arbitrary OS/application from FLASH
- capable of booting an arbitrary OS/application from ethernet
- capable of booting over serial port desirable, not critical
- must have at least one USB 2.0 port. more::=better
- must operate from a single-voltage DC supply (not more than 28V, not more than 25W)
- prefer Not to have PS/2 keyboard & mouse interfaces
- prefer Not to have any graphics capability
- built-in SPI, I2C, or general-purpose discrete I/O bonus
- price point under $250

The mission for this SBC is to sit on my network and operate custom I/O hardware. Heaviest possible use case required would be to support a USB web-cam and serve low-bandwidth (CIF) video through a custom server app. Definitely not required to run databases, web servers, web browsers, middle-ware, ESB, or anything like that. Intended s/w platform C/C++, and maybe, just maybe, J2ME or J2SE.

The best match I've found so far is the [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) ,  but this falls short by having graphics capability (not needed) in place of ethernet capability (mandatory). I know you can add a USB based ethernet adapter, but ideally there would be a better match that would render this not necessary. There are also some atom-based 'car PCs' that are near misses, mainly for power supply reasons.

Comment: What does SBC stand for?

Comment: Single Board Computer

Comment: He is not the only one to wonder that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Kind of a repeat from my answer to the previous question, but with a new board.) I'd go for the [Technologic Systems TS-7553](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=TS-7553#) for $135-- slightly cheaper than the Beagleboard, and just as good. I haven't actually used the 7553, but I've used its predecessors, the TS-7500 and TS-7550, and they're good. The only requirement it might not meet out of the box is booting over Ethernet, but I know it can be configured to do so (at least via TFTP or NFS).

(Maybe this goes without saying, but I have no connection to Technologic Systems at all. I've just used some of their boards.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is quite a sbc, but the [guruplug server plus](http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/p-32-guruplug-server-plus.aspx) has usb, 2x ethernet, uart, i2c, spi, jtag (with an adapter), microsd, no gfx, no ps/2, serial port booting (with an adapter) and runs linux from flash on an arm core. Maybe take a look at it ? With minimal trickery you could run it off a DC supply. They run for US$129.

Comment: Overall, looks quite good. The power supply looks to be the main drawback.. though I'm wondering, if it only pulls 5 watts, how tough could that be.

Comment: 5 watts at 1.6 volts can be hard. Although I have no idea what voltage it takes and am just adding this comment as a side note.

Answer (score 1):

[ArmKits.com](http://www.armkits.com/) has quite a few boards that meet those specs under $200 without an LCD screen, but has a VGA port.  The [SBC9261-I](http://www.armkits.com/Product/SBC9261-I.asp) is one of them. The [SOC8200](http://www.armkits.com/Product/soc8200.asp) has a VGA expansion port, but I don't know the price. I would order from their US distributor, [IESDistribution](http://www.iesdistribution.com/) to save money on shipping.

[PCEngines](http://www.pcengines.ch) has an [Alix3d3](http://www.pcengines.ch/alix3d3.htm) that might meet your needs for $111.  There's an I2Cs bus option for it as well as some enclosures you might buy for it from them.  Also an 18 V power supply can be ordered for it.

Answer (score 1):

How about a [Gumstix](https://www.gumstix.com/index.html)

Edit: fixed broken URL.

Comment: I think the Gumstix boards are perfect when you need small size, but they're a little more expensive than the competition.

Comment: They kill me in price. I like them, but I would much rather make my own 20 dollar solution then spend a couple hundred on that. I guess i do not value my time well enough.