# MATLAB toolbox equivalent for embedded system

Tags: c, c++, matlab

We have to develop control software to run in an embedded system. The prototype is made in Matlab (using neural network toolbox), and we want to port the software to C or C++. Do you know which libraries or software we could use to do this? Embedded matlab may be another option, but, from their info in the website, it seems that neural network toolbox is not supported. Any of you has worked with it before?

Comment: @farshad, direct email is not what this site is for. You may ask questions on this site and get answers, but direct contact is not the goal, if he helps you in private no-one else learns. If it is something that only benefits you, well, you should probably hire someone.

Answer (score 5):

First dump it to C/C++, [instructions here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-19HN4/index.html?product=NN&solution=1-19HN4) and profile the application on your computer. neural networks can be rather compute intensive so you need to know how much processing power and what type of processing you need (integer? FP? fixed point? SIMD? etc?).

If you need the network to be trainable while running on your embedded device, then you're stuck developing your own system as MatLab exported code doesn't including the training portions, perhaps based on some external neural network libraries.  I would still start with profiling what you've got to get an idea of what class of device your looking at.

All that being said, the [beagleboard](http://beagleboard.org/) is probably a safe bet unless what your doing is very compute intensive, it would also allow you to use most linux libraries.  I used [the FANN library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fann/) for a project maybe 5 years ago and it was good to work with.  I don't know if it will compile for ARM out of the box or if some other library has trumped it recently.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on porting the software to C/C++ anyway, you could run it on almost any embedded system with an operating system. You might start with an embedded Linux board, since it has free C and C++ compilers.

As far as the actual hardware goes, there are many choices. Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/linux-sbc-recommendations) for some suggestions. You might also consider the [mbed](http://mbed.org), which is cheap, has a free C compiler, and is easy to get started with if you're new to embedded stuff.